# facebook sdk: share local picture with text is driving me crazy

Tags: android, facebook, share, local

**GOAL**

In my camera app i want to let user share a picture with pre-formatted text and a description on the user's facebook wall.

**INTRO**

I Googled a lot and followed "the terrific" [facebook-getting-started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/), trying many things, for !!days!!... no completely working solutions found yet.

At least i think i got some points:

1. The great Android Intent action_send works great but not choosing facebook, that works for text OR for pictures, not for both (!!), see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423)
2. applicationID, hashxxx, and everything else needed to link android app to facebook login, all things that i really don't understand and don't want to, done and at last working (thanx facebook for all this sh*t!!)
3. share with facebook can be done (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share)):
   3a. using the facebook app (installed in the device)
   3b. using a login session (if facebook app is not installed)
4. Facebook wants us to use its SDK, it's very [b|s]ad, but i can stand it.
5. case 3a - facebook suggests us to use the shareDialog, and -fighting a lot with code snippets and samples suggested!- i have been able to do it, but i need it to work also if facebook app is not installed (case 3b.)
6. case 3b - facebook suggests to use the "ugly" feedDialog as a fallback (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkfeed)).
   6a. feedDialog needs login and it's ok...
   6b. it seems feedDialog cannot share local images, i really don't understand why... [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0#params) facebook guide talks only about "URL" for the "picture" keyword...
   5c. then i think i must use Request, i tried implementing it but nothing happened, i think i'm missing something... No useful references (=working examples) found.

**CODE SNIPPETS** copy/paste/edit from SO and developers.facebook

ShareDialog and session management in case facebook app is not installed **IT'S WORKING**

```
/**
 * share image with facebook, using facebook sdk
 * @param pathToImage
 */
private void shareWithFacebook(String pathToImage) {
    Log.i("SHARE", "share with facebook");
    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
        // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
        Log.i("SHARE", "share with ShareDialog");
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
        .setCaption("Sharing photo taken with MyApp.")
        .setName("Snail Camera Photo")
        .setPicture("file://"+pathToImage)
        .setLink("http://myapplink")
        .setDescription("Image taken with MyApp for Android")
        .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    } else {
        // maybe no facebook app installed, trying an alternative
        // here i think i need a session
        if (Session.getActiveSession() != null && Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) {
            publishFeedDialog(pathToImage);
        } else {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {

                List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
                permissions.add("publish_actions");

                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                    .setPermissions(permissions)
                    .setCallback(mFacebookCallback));
            } else {
                Session.openActiveSession(this, true, mFacebookCallback);
            }
        }
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback mFacebookCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            String facebookToken = session.getAccessToken();
            Log.i("SHARE", facebookToken);
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, com.facebook.Response response) {
                    publishFeedDialog(MP.LAST_TAKEN_FOR_GALLERY);
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
    }
};
```

feedDialog snippet, **works for text fields, links, and remote url, but DOESN'T WORK FOR LOCAL PICTURES** using "file://..." nor "file:///...". Error message: `picture URL is not properly formatted`.

```
private void publishFeedDialog(String pathToImage) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "myapp Photo");
    params.putString("caption", "Sharing photo taken with myapp.");
    params.putString("description", "Image taken with myapp for Android");
    params.putString("link", "http://myapp.at.playstore");
    params.putString("picture", "file://"+pathToImage);


    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(EnhancedCameraPreviewActivity.this,//getApplicationContext(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                Log.i("SHARE", "feedDialog.onComplete");
                if (error == null) {
                    // story is posted
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Another try, using **Request**, it says:

> photo upload problem. Error={HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200,
>   errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Requires extended
>   permission: publish_actions}

I tried adding publish_actions permission in the session management above, maybe i miss something...

```
private void publishFeedDialog(String pathToImage) {
    Request request=Request.newPostOpenGraphObjectRequest(
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            "PhotoUpload",
            "myApp Photo Upload",
            "file://"+pathToImage,
            "http://myapp.at.playstore",
            "Image taken with myApp for Android",
            null,
            uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Last try with **Request**, absolutely nothing happens, both with or without "picture" keyword.

```
private void publishFeedDialog(String pathToImage) {
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", "Image taken with myApp for Android");
    parameters.putString("picture", "file://"+pathToImage);
    parameters.putString("caption", "myApp Photo");

    Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/feed", parameters, null);
    // also tried: Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/feed", parameters, com.facebook.HttpMethod.POST);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

**QUESTIONS**

-1- Are there some faults in my 1..6 points?

-2- Can i share a local picture using FeedDialog?

-3- if not, how to when facebook app is not installed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but I have a workaround.

1. I can't find any wrong reasoning in your point 1-6, look like the same issues I've come acrossed.
2. You can't share pictures locally, **but...**
3. Code snippet below:

This will upload the picture to the users profile and post it on his\hers wall, afterwhich you can get the URL if needed:

```
private void uploadPicture(final String message, Session session) {
        Request.Callback uploadPhotoRequestCallback = new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(com.facebook.Response response) {
                if (response.getError() != null) { 
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed posting on the Wall", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

            Object graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getProperty("id");
            if (graphResponse == null || !(graphResponse instanceof String) ||
                    TextUtils.isEmpty((String) graphResponse)) { 
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed uploading the photo\no respons", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Succsefully posted on the facebook Wall", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }                
        }
    };

    // Execute the request with the image and appropriate message
    Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(session, profileBitmap, uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
    Bundle params = request.getParameters();
    params.putString("message", message);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

And to start facebook login when you don't have the APP, it's simpler, I use the following code snippet for calling the facebook SDK on facebook button:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.faceBookButton:
                        if (((imagePath != null && !imagePath.equals("")) || (message != null && !message.equals("")))) {
                            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                            if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
                                session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                                        .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "publish_actions"))
                                        .setCallback(statusCallback));
                            } else {
                                if (profileBitmap != null) {
                                    uploadPicture(message, session);
                                } else {
                                    publishFeedDialog(message);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.checkin_fail), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                  break;
           }      
     }
```

In my case publishFeedDialog accepts the message you want to pass on, and not the image, but it doesn't matter. It opens up Facebook's message dialog anyway to which I haven't yet found a way to pass a predefined message from my EditText widget.